# Running VScode Jupyter Notebook cells in already open and configured python terminal (rather than open a new terminal)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am trying to run my Jupyter notebook cell in a terminal running in a virtual environment and running on a specific node that I had requested via SLURM, but whenever I try to run the cell in a python terminal, it opens a fresh python terminal which has none of the configurations that are required.

I can do this on R (when I click cntrl enter, it runs in the already open R terminal), but it seems python is not able to do this yet or I don't know how to configure it to do this.

Right now, I get around it by copying and pasting each line of code into the python terminal and running, but I wish I could find a more elegant way to do this.

Please let me know if this is a similar issue with yours and if you have been able to solve it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKQWb.png Why do you want to run jupyter in the terminal? ipynb file has separate code blocks.

Comment: Hi @MingJie-MSFT. I want to run the codeblocks in an ipynb file but I want the code to be run in a specific conda environment and in a specific node (I am using SLURM for job scheduling and managing nodes). Please, I'd appreciate suggestions on a better way to phrase my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the kernel of jupyter by clicking on the upper right corner:

[image]

Use the command "python: select interpreter" to modify the current interpreter at the same time

Comment: Hi @MingJie-MSFT, thank you! I really appreciate your responses. I have done what you suggested in the past and it solves the problem of using a particular python in a conda env. My challenge remains to use the particular SLURM node I have requested which has high memory. Is there any way to:
1) Request a compute node using SLURM within Jupyter, such that when I run cells, this node (with higher memory) will be where the code task is computed. OR
2) Make Jupyter send the code to be run to an already open python terminal that has been pre-set using both SLURM and conda?

Comment: For your next two questions, I don't think this can work. Jupiter uses an independent kernel. If you want to do what you said, I suggest you use python.